# Woocommerce Subscriptions - Move file to theme folder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

Is it possible to move a copy of a file from the plugin to the theme folder?

I know this can be done with templates, but the file I wish to move and edit is located at woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-product.php

I've tried moving it to the woocommerce folder in my theme, as well as a 'includes' folder in my theme.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot override php classes like that, this can only be achieved through [filters and action hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/).

You can move plugin code to your theme by integrating the whole plugin into your theme but this is **highly unadvised** due to the code not getting any updates and a variety of security and maintainability issues in the future.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It can probably be done via a filter anyway, it's been a long couple of days and was getting desperate I guess 